# How to track mouse movement on Google TV

Tags: android, google-tv

I use a Sony Google TV. If I click on the trackpad, it'll fire a onTouchEvent. But if I only slide on the touchpad (ie: moving the arrow), i dont see any onTouchEvent, neither onTrackBall event. 
Any hints about the way to track the touchpad/mouse movement?

Comment: GoogleTV is a non touchscreen device. Using touchpad slide movements for your app is not recommended. Is there any way you could avoid using that, and use the dpad instead?

Comment: The aim is to port a drawing app. D-pad is not very usable for this usage thats why I wanted to use touchpad. Btw, can you share what are minimal hardware requirement for input in google TV? I guess there is at least d-pad. Are keyboard, touchpad part of minimal requirement?

Comment: The Google TV requirements call for at least Mouse cursor & click.  (What kind of device is left up to the OEM) It's currently a track pad on a Revue and a optical pointing device on a Sony.  You can imagine other ways of doing this as well.  The up/down/left/right/ok of the d-pad are required, but the orientation is not, but strongly recommended.  We hope to get the formal specification published publicly soon, but I don't have a date for it.

Comment: How can i track mouse cursor movment in apps? I tought it would be onTouchEvent, but this method is only called when I do mouse click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`onGenericMotionEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onGenericMotionEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)).

You can also add an `OnGenericMotionEventListener`.